# Hex axial coordinates to table coordinates conversion

Tags: mathematics, tilemap, maps, hexagonal-grid

I am developing a browser game based on a hex map. I am storing my data based on axial coordinates system.

[image: Axial]

**I developed a function which shows me axial coordinates of hexes within `$distance` from a given hex. Now I want to show those hexes in a form in a HTML table.**

The data that I have is only axial coordinates of center hex as well a list of axial coordinates of hexes within distance (not sorted in any way)

As shown in the transition scheme below, hexes may always be shown in form of a simple HTML table:

[image: TableToHexes]

But I am struggling at how to get each of the map hexes shown in a correct table field (row/column) of the table, assuming that table numbering looks like this:

[image]

To solve this out it seems to me that in first instance I need to determine the size of the HTML table that I need. If I will be able to determine what is table coordinate of center of the HTML table then I would be able to find out localisation of each hex in reference to the center hex.

In case of `$distance = 1` I need 3 columns and 3 rows:

[image]

In case of `$distance = 2` I need 5 columns and 5 rows:

[image]

This leads me to the conclusion that my required HTLM table size is:

```
$distance *2 + 1
```

The center hex lies in the middle of the table, so its coordinates are:

```
($distance *2 + 2) /2
```

But what is next, how to convert axial coordinates to table coordinates?

Comment: Looking at the 5x5 table, it looks like the first number is the table row and the second number is the table column.

Comment: This is a great guide to this: http://www.redblobgames.com/grids/hexagons/